# AlarmManager stops running

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-service

I'm writing a program that should run every 10 minutes in the background.  The code I have seems to work fine as long as I'm actively using my phone, but after a long period of time, say overnight, the process seems to stop on it's own.  When my program is running as it should I can view it under the "cached process" on my device, but then it will stop showing in the list after awhile.

I was reading about [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) and was wondering if I need to use that.  As I understand it, it will keep your background process running even if the phone sleeps.  Not sure what "sleep" means in Android, if it's when you power off, or does the phone go into a "sleep" state if it's not used for awhile.

This is the code I'm using:

Main class:

```
 public class Main extends ListActivity
 {
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
      {
           AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

           Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
           PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
           alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

           alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 600000, 600000, pendingIntent);
      }
 }
```

BroadcastReceiver class:

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
 {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
      { 
           context.startService(new Intent(context, MainService.class));
      }
 }
```

Service class:

```
 public class MainService extends Service  
 {  

protected void handleIntent(Intent intent) 
{
    // obtain the wake lock 
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE); 
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag"); 
    mWakeLock.acquire(); // check the global background data setting 
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 

    if (!cm.getBackgroundDataSetting()) 
    { 
        stopSelf();
        return; 
    }

    new FetchItems().execute();
}
 }

 private class FetchItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
 {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) 
    {           
      SomeLongProcess();
      return null;
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {   
        stopSelf();
    }
 }

 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
 {
   handleIntent(intent);
   return START_STICKY;
 }

 @Override 
 public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) { 
   handleIntent(intent); 
 }

@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
         super.onDestroy(); 

         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

         Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
         alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

      mWakeLock.release();
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"> 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it really have to run every ten minutes even when the device is asleep? If it doesn't, use `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME` and your service will be run when the device is wakes up, saving *a lot* of battery. As for your question, you can assume that the screen going dark == going to sleep (of course, if other services are holding wakelocks, that is not the case).

Comment: That's a good question.  The program I'm writing is basically an RSS reader and, in the settings, the user can specify whether they want automatic updates or not, so I'm guessing it should run when the device is asleep, otherwise it will only update their feeds when they are using their phone.

Comment: Unless the first thing they open when they wake up the phone is your app, you will have enough time to cache the feed. Consider this: the user (and the phone) is asleep for 8 hours, and you will be running your service 48 times in that time. RSS is not critical data, you  might wan to relax your requirements a bit, in the interest of saving some battery.

Comment: That's true.  I actually have it setup where the user can pick the time interval they want with a message saying the shorter the interval, the more the battery will be used.  They can pick anywhere from 5 minutes to 5 hours.  I just didn't want to put that into my code above, since it didn't seem relevant.  But the question still remains as to why the service stops running when the phone hasn't been used in awhile.

Comment: If throws an uncaught exception or the process killed, relevant alarms will be cleared. You might examine the logcat and add some logging to your service and receiver.

Comment: That's good to know.  I wasn't exactly sure if AlarmManager stops itself if the device sleeps and I need to use something like WakefulIntentService, but it sounds like AlarmManager should, if everything is working, run non-stop.  I will look for any exceptions being thrown.  Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't assume that when the screen is off, the device is asleep. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/Airlo3g5luw).

Comment: Sure, but having a bunch of things holding wakelocks and running stuff while it is supposed to be asleep is not a good thing.