# Android: After a long sleep, AlarmManager stops updating

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I'm using the following code to schedule a service once a minute:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 60 * 1000, createFrequentUpdateIntent(context));
```

Everything works OK for some time, but after a few hours I stop receiving the update intent. I wake the phone up, wait a few minutes and nothing happens.

How can I solve this?

Comment: look it this it is similar to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410646/alarmmanager-stops-running

Comment: Does it happen on one particular device or on different devices?

Comment: Omarj, the question you're referring to is not mine. And it's different: Kris was using `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` and I'm using `RTC`. Actually the answer he accepted was to stop using `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`.

Comment: Use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to examine the scheduled alarms after it stops working.

Comment: have you found the problem ? I am also facing this issue

Comment: @jacob Unfortunately I don't remember. Anyway, take a look at the plans for Android Marshmallow. Most apps that are using alarms will soon need redesign.