# Android AlarmManager stops working after long sleep

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am starting the AlarmManager like so:

```
long systemTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, systemTime, intervalMillis, pendingIntent);
```

Every works fine until the device goes to sleep for a long time, then when the device wakes up the alarms are never triggered again. This is similar to [Android: After a long sleep, AlarmManager stops updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382967/android-after-a-long-sleep-alarmmanager-stops-updating) and [AlarmManager stops running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410646/alarmmanager-stops-running), however im already using `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME`so they are no help.

I do not want the AlarmManager to wake up the device, but I do want it to continue when the device has woken up. How do I fix this?

Comment: Use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` sometime when your alarms stop working, to see if the alarm is still scheduled (and if so, when it will be invoked again), or if the alarm has somehow been canceled.

Comment: I had a bug in my start/stop code made obivious by that command. Thanks

Comment: can you advise what the bug was @meeeee? I'm facing a similar issue